# Antonym for cumulative

Tags: antonyms

If odometer provides cumulative data.
Then which type of data speedometer provides ?

I mean that every measurement of that type of data is a separate value and do not depends on previous or next one in opposite to cumulative data.

How we can describe this type of data in English?

Comment: Have you considered *individual* or *discrete*?

Comment: Discrete is good, I like it and clearly understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Velocity's an integral of acceleration, while displacement's an integral of velocity.  That is, both speed and distance are cumulative quantities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speedometer provides ***instantaneous*** data: it shows the value at that instant.

> When using GRIDc data, note that there are two types of data available: Instantaneous and Cumulative.
>
> Temperature is what we call instantaneous data. Instantaneous data does not require manipulation. In other words, at any given time, you can look up the data, and without manipulation, find the exact value you are looking for. Wind speed is another example that fits in the category.
>
> http://www.gridc.net/page/instantaneous-cumulative

Comment: This is correct as in physics, a speedometer shows the *instantaneous* speed of the vehicle as opposed to the "average speed" which is a result of a calculation of two different variables called distance and time.

Comment: Though it's an official term, i didn't know, it is probably the answer to my question. Thank you Andrew ! But I also like the word 'discrete' mentioned above. It looks more simple for ordinary people.