# Discrete data vs cumulative data

Tags: logic

1)Can we use discrete data as antonym for cumulative data ? 
2)can discrete data  be cumulative data?
Simple yes/no in both cases would suffice.

Comment: The concept you are seeking is not clear. Can you expand?

Comment: Hugely related and possibly a duplicate: [Antonym for cumulative](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145276/antonym-for-cumulative). I think the answer is No. *Discrete* does not necessarily mean *instantaneous*.

Comment: Yes, depending on context, that could be the best word after all. Remember, the context!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Who said *instantaneous* now?

Comment: You might describe it as a data "break out/down" (or "samples"), and the cumulative might also be described as "aggregated" data.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to prove tchrist wrong !! Because he suggested discrete as an antonym for cumulative and the one who asked about gave him acceptance...I just wanted to point out discrete doesn't make logic and is out of context /not related to concept...

Answer (score 2):

From [mathsisfun...](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/data-discrete-continuous.html)

> ***Discrete data** is counted, **Continuous data** is measured*.
>    .
>    Discrete Data can only take certain values.
>    Example: The number of students in a class (you can't have half a student).
>   .
>   Continuous Data can take any value (within a range)
>   Example: Time in a race (you could measure it to any arbitrary level of accuracy).

From [yourdictionary...](http://www.yourdictionary.com/cumulative-data)

> ***cumulative data** is information gathered over a period of time.*
>    Example: a graph showing how a company's sales have increased since the beginning of the year.

---

I think that's enough to show that in OP's context, *discrete/continuous* are antonyms. That distinction doesn't really relate to the concept of ***cumulative*** data - for which I would say the relevant antonym is [***snapshot*** data](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22snapshot%20data%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (data values recorded at one specific point in time).

Comment: This leaves me a little wanting and I don't know why, possibly context. I think I have read the phrase "discrete time signal" for example, possibly in relation to sample rates and time sampling (a discrete measure of a continuous signal).

Comment: @horatio: I'm no mathematician, but the bare bones of the distinction between [discrete-time signal and continuous-time signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_signal) as explained in that Wikipedia link seems straightforward enough. *And* it's consistent with the definitions I cited above. I think maybe your problems might relate more to the *concepts* than the words themselves, in which case perhaps you would get more help on [maths.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)